# Is it possible to detect when the passcode on an iOS device is modified?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

For example: I have an app which use FaceID to login and passcode is "1111".
when I change my passcode to "2222" and relaunch the app, it will detect that my password is modified and logout from the app automatically.

So is it possible to to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have this information with [evaluatedPolicyDomainState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514150-evaluatedpolicydomainstate)

> It can be used to compare with other values returned by this property to determine whether the authorized database has been updated

Code exemple :

> Swift

```
let localAuthContext = LAContext()
if localAuthContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: error) {
    if oldBiometryData != nil && localAuthContext.evaluatedPolicyDomainState != oldBiometryData {
         changed = true
    }
}
```

> Objective-C

```
LAContext *localAuthenticationContext = [LAContext new];
if ([localAuthenticationContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error]) {
    if (oldBiometryData != nil && ![localAuthenticationContext.evaluatedPolicyDomainState isEqualToData:oldBiometryData]) {
        changed = YES;
    }
}
```

With `oldBiometryData` the previous biometry data that you store in your app.